# df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv') pointing to file in azure blob reports [errno 2] no such file or directory

Tags: python, pandas, azure, csv

I'm working my way through the instructions posted at
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory#:~:text=%20Tutorial%3A%20Run%20Python%20scripts%20through%20Azure%20Data,create%20the%20Batch%20pool%20that%20your...%20More%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory#:%7E:text=%20Tutorial%3A%20Run%20Python%20scripts%20through%20Azure%20Data,create%20the%20Batch%20pool%20that%20your...%20More%20)

That site provide some python code.

I'm trying to get that code to work.

Here is my code so far.

'''

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
containerName      = "output"
storageAccountURL= "<URL to my storage account>"
storageKey= "<storage key >"

    
# Establish connection with the blob storage account
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storageAccountURL,
                                   credential=storageKey

# Load iris dataset from the task node
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
# Subset records
df = df[df['Species'] == "setosa"]
# Save the subset of the iris dataframe locally in task node
df.to_csv("iris_setosa.csv", index = False)
# Upload iris dataset
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(containerName)
with open("iris_setosa.csv", "rb") as data:
blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name="iris_setosa.csv", data=data)  
'''
```

When I run the above code ( in visual studio 2019 , on my laptop ), the line
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')   causes the following error ;-
[errno 2] No such file or directory :'iris.csv'

Now, I have checked that the blob container input does in fact contain that file. I can see it and I can even download it, open it, etc.

I have tried various changes to the code;-
changed the containerName from output to input ( because the instructions on the web prior to to code mentions that input folder. No improvement.

I tried various changes to the file name . ..

```
df = pd.read_csv('/iris.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('input/iris.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(<the files hyper-link >)
```

no luck

I've read the various posts about fixing the import commands dependent on different azure python sdk and library versions, and the imports work OK, but I cannot solve the above pd.read_cvs problem.

To add to the above information ...

I'm using python 3.7,

and the following python libraries;-

```
azure-batch==10.0.0 
azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision==3.1.0 
azure-common==1.1.26 
azure-core==1.10.0
 pandas==1.2.1
```

and other packages.

Can you help by telling me how to get this python code to work ?

many thanks

Comment: please add additional information as an edit to the question and not as a comment

Comment: Your issue here is your running a local python file where as the documentation expects a batch file python job in Datafactory i.e in the cloud - if you want to use this above code then you need to locally download the file and have it in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically speaking, if you're certain that the file is there, and based on the fact that it seems like you're running Python through Azure, the issure here is that your current working directory (cwd) does not match the "default" working directory that the tutorial expects. Considering how the tutorial is written, they expect you to be working from the input container. Therefore, to resolve the issue, you need to correctly find the path to your file or change your cwd.

Within Python, you can check what your cwd is using:

`import os`

`os.getcwd()`

I advise you to do that and from there you should be able to find the path to your file. You could also just change your working directory using `os.chdir(path)` where you replace `path` with the path to the input folder where the dataset is stored.

Comment: Thank you for resolving my confusion. I fixed the error by fully defining the complete path to the iris.csv file.